I am trying to implement google signin and i am passing IdToken to backend and get: Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim

Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "test-f2978" but got "583659997900-tiqii1rc4mjsle349h42nq117h36fvbb.apps.googleusercontent.com". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

FrontEnd Code :-
useEffect(() =\> {
// Configure Google Sign-in with the web client ID
GoogleSignin.configure({
webClientId: '583659997900-tiqii1rc4mjsle349h42nq117h36fvbb.apps.googleusercontent.com',
});
}, \[\]);

// Function to handle Google login
const handleGoogleLogin = async () =\> {
setIsLoading(true);
try {
// Check if Google Play Services are available
await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });

  // Sign in with Google
  const response = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  console.log(response);
  
  const idToken = response.data?.idToken;
  console.log(idToken);
  
   // Send the ID token to your backend for verification and custom token generation
  const authToken = await signIn(idToken); 
  
  console.log(authToken);

}

Heres the frontend code the IdToken generated in frontend is passed to a fucntion it handles the response from backend and it gets the token from backend .
Backend Code:-
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase-admin-sdk.json');
admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),  
});
app.post("/api/generate-token", async (req, res) =\> {
const { idToken } = req.body;
try {
const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
const uid = decodedToken.uid;
res.status(200).json({
  message: "User signed in successfully",
  user: {
    uid: uid,
    email: decodedToken.email,
  },
});

} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
res.status(401).json({
message: "Invalid token",
error: error.message,
});
}
});


The Firebase code in your backend can't validate the token you pass, because it's not a valid Firebase ID token. You're retrieving an OAuth2 token from Google sign-in, but are not signing in to Firebase yet.
To sign in to Firebase with the OAuth token that you get back from GoogleSignin, pass the token you get from Google sign-in to Firebase:
...
// Create a Google credential with the token
const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(signInResult.data.token);

// Sign-in the user with the credential
return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);

This is from the documentation on signing in to Firebase with Google sign-in in the React Native Firebase documentation, so I recommend keeping that handy.

I added google credential and in my code and returing token generated yet its the same  . i am using backend to verify it in place of  the return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);  is raising an error [Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()]   so to fix it i added that functionality in backend to verify it .

First off: does it make sense why your existing code didn't work (trying to verify an OAuth2 token as if its a Firebase ID token)? And why the change I describe in my answer would fix that specific problem? You may have another problem after that, but it's a different problem. Even if for you it's still part of the same use-case, you'll need to post a new question with a new minimal repro of the situation that you now have. --- [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]
